# Get time since last keystroke

Tags: key-bindings, advice, keystrokes, timers, idle-timer

I would like to know how many seconds have passed since the last keystroke (or character that showed up in the screen, whatever is easier).

Is there a timer that is associated to `self-insert-command`?  Alternatively, what is a simple way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Maybe have a look at how auto save works (especially, there's a variable `auto-save-timeout`).

Comment: Could it be that this is an [X-Y-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/232422) and you are actually looking for [`run-with-idle-timer`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Idle-Timers.html)? Otherwise `current-idle-time` does what you want.

Comment: @Tobias: Yes, `(nth 1 (current-idle-time))` was what I was looking for.